# Trying to print an increasing number pyramid with lines on the sides, using only nested for loops (Java)

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, nested-loops

I'm a beginner at Java.
I was solving nested for loop questions... Then this question came up. After research and re-tries I couldn't get my head around it. It must be solved using **only** nested for loops.

This is what the question wants my code to output:

```
-----1-----
----333----
---55555---
--7777777--
-999999999-
```

This is as close as I got:

```
---------1
-------333
-----55555
---7777777
-999999999
```

This is my code:

```
for (int line = 1; line <= 9; line+=2) {
    for (int j = 1; j <= (-1 * line + 10); j++) {
        System.out.print("-");
    }
    for (int k = 1; k <= line; k++) {
        System.out.print(line);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: You need three inner loops, not just two, one each for the leading "-" sequence, the line number sequence, and the trailing "-" sequence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to add another for loop to print `-` on the right side.
Also now the first and the third loop will execute for half the number of times

```java
for (int line = 1; line <= 9; line+=2) {
    for (int j = 0; j <= (-1 * line + 10) / 2; j++) {
        System.out.print("-");
    }
    for (int k = 1; k <= line; k++) {
        System.out.print(line);
    }
    for (int j = 0; j <= (-1 * line + 10) / 2; j++) {
        System.out.print("-");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Do you know why it prints 5 lines on the first lap, instead of 4?       (-1 * 1 + 10) / 2 = 4, but for some reason it prints 5 lines? And on the other remaining laps, it again, prints 1 more than the amount it should print.                                                    Edit: Nevermind, it does that because it starts from 0 :D